# An efficient way to render similar objects in Qt3D?

Tags: qt, qt3d

I need to render hundreds of objects sharing their mesh and material (and having different `QTransform`s). The only way I found is to create an instance of `QEntity` for each of them. Each would be holding an instance of the mesh and of the material resulting in a huge waste of time and memory.

Is there a way to make this more efficient? I know that using raw OpenGL you can reuse meshes and shaders loading them once and using with different transforms and shader parameters many times in the same frame. Maybe Qt3D has something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same mesh or material on multiple entities by adding them to the list of components of each entity:

```
QEntity *root = new QEntity();
QMesh *mesh = new QMesh(root);
QEntity *item1 = new QEntity (root);
QEntity *item2 = new QEntity (root);
item1->addComponent(mesh);
item2->addComponent(mesh);
```

Comment: It should be noted that as you re-add the same component many times into the scene, it becomes infinitely slow to do so. `Qt3DCore::QScene::hasEntityForComponent()` appears to have linear speed to the amount of identical components or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

While you can share the mesh between several entities, the most efficient way to render the same geometry thousands of times is to use instanced rendering (since you'll end up with one draw call rather than thousands).

See the [instanced-arrays-qml](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/examples/qt3d/instanced-arrays-qml?h=5.10.1) example that comes with Qt 3D.